# Gmail: "Couldn't sign in" error with latest version, but other google apps sync just fine. Older Gmail version works fine

Tags: sync, gmail

While using the latest version of the Gmail app: 6.3.117716127, I cannot sync my mail whatsoever.

Update: 6.4.120760496 has the same issue.

*Please note that this is NOT a universal "Google" sign in problem, where you get a black background with white text and you have to enter your credentials, although the message is the same ("Couldn't sign in")*

This is for the Gmail app only. Observe the error in my screenshot below:

[image: Screenshot of GMail with sign in error]

Tapping "Sign in" just makes the message at the bottom go away, but nothing else happens, and it doesn't sync. If I try refreshing my inbox, it will bring that sign-in message back.

My last sync with the newest version was April 13th. Then I reverted back to an older version of Gmail from November of 2015. *That version syncs just fine*.
You can see email from April 19 in the screenshot, because I tried upgrading back to the latest version, but it still wouldn't sync.

Deleting the cache and data doesn't help.

I did not change my Google password.

My phone is a Galaxy S4 running Android 4.4.2 (Hyperdrive)

Comment: Same issue on my Samsung Galaxy Note 4 starting from 6PM April 21, 2016 (last successful sync) on the same stock Android 4.4.2 Hyperdrive. Did you find solution?

Comment: No, I am still using an old apk. My only bet right now is to wait for another update to gmail. I'll be sure to update this question if I find anything.

Comment: [What's wrong with this question?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2458)

Comment: I think it's a problem of the Gmail app itself. Does it work in other devices ?

Comment: You deleted the cache/data of the gmail app?  See also https://forums.androidcentral.com/google-nexus-4/314980-problems-gmail-i-keep-getting-message-saying-couldnt-sign.html

Comment: Its time to update your phone or buy a new one. Its possible to update to Android 6, 7, 9 with a custom ROM. Android 4.4.2 is no longer among the used things, that's why you have problems. The GMAIL app requires certain regulations and security features to be followed. The old apps do not have them. This is why its not working probably, also the access for less secure apps in you google account is probably disabled. You can try enabling it. Soon I will receive the Ulefone Armor X7 and Xperia X Compact, I can recommend you a phone if you want.

Comment: @CFCBazarcom Who are you replying to? This question was asked in 2016.

Comment: If its not accepted to answer, I will delete my comment. I see a highly active question and it appears at the beginning of the search.

Answer (score 1):

Android 4.4.2 is officially discontinued for newer Gmail versions.

That's all.

You can check out custom ROMs like [this](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/jdcteam-optimized-lineageos18-1-v5-0-7aug.4203927/) that is made on top of latest Android versions to upgrade your device's OS.